# Prolog database with automatic retraction on backtracking

Tags: prolog

Are there any Prolog implementations supporting retractable database? I mean a database that automatically retract a fact inserted by assert() predicate call when the prolog engine backtracks through this predicate call? In other words, I'd want an "automatic" implicit retraction on backtracking.

Something similar may be expressed as

```
my_assert(Fact):- assert(Fact).
my_assert(Fact):- retract(Fact), fail.
```

but that wouldn't work properly while backtracking through cutting (!)

Or this goal may be achieved in some manner using "tabled" flavours of Prolog?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any Prolog implementations that natively supports what you want.  You could implement something similar on top of [setup_call_cleanup/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=setup_call_cleanup/3) with a continuation passing style:

```
% assert Fact while seeking Goal then retract Fact
assert_then(Fact, Goal) :-
  setup_call_cleanup(assert(Fact), Goal, retract(Fact)).

:- dynamic whom/1.
example :-
    assert_then(whom(world), hello).
hello :-
    whom(Whom),
    format('Hello ~w~n', [Whom]).
```

It's kind of ugly but should work with backtracking, exceptions and cut.

Comment: Interesting (+1), however, rewriting the program fully in continuation-passing style is a challenge :).

Answer (score 1):

This library might be of use to you https://github.com/tef/nomads

It uses various prolog term rewriting tricks to mimic adding an additional parameter to all your predicates holding asserted facts.

Comment: As I understand, logical state thread simply allows to model a database "as a data structure" (representing "list of all asserted facts" in some form) in more convinient way? The "thread" allows not to pass the corresponding arguments (representing the "old" and "new" datatabase state) through all predicates, having this argument implicitly defined (?). If so,it is rather what I'd want to avoid (i.e modeling a database with some data structure passed through parameters). However, it is an interesting technique anyway, so thank you for the reference (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Necro, But I had the same question and I tried something with a combination of nb_setval and b_setval. It seems to work for the simpler cases, but I've not tested it out on harder ones yet. The major difference is that you can't query a b_assert'ed fact directly, but will have to use b_query.

```
:- dynamic b_asserted/2.

:- nb_setval(b_assert_nbc, 0), nb_setval(b_assert_bc, 0).

b_assert(What):-
    b_assert_maintain_consistency,
    b_getval(b_assert_nbc, NBC),
    AssertId is NBC+1,
    assert(b_asserted(AssertId, What)),
    nb_setval(b_assert_nbc, AssertId),
    b_setval(b_assert_bc, AssertId).

b_query(What):-
    b_assert_maintain_consistency,
    b_asserted(_, What).

% The overhead
b_assert_maintain_consistency:-
    nb_getval(b_assert_nbc, NBC),
    b_getval(b_assert_bc, BC), % BC < NBC if backtracking happened
    b_assert_restore_consistency(BC, NBC).

b_assert_restore_consistency(C, C):- !.
b_assert_restore_consistency(BC, NBC):-
    BC1 is BC+1,
    (between(BC1, NBC, DeleteMe), retract(b_asserted(DeleteMe, _)), fail; true),
    nb_setval(b_assert_nbc, BC).
```

If this works, bonus would be to figure out b_retract. Maybe we b_assert(b_retracted(What)) and replay the asserts and retracts in b_query?

Answer (score 0):

In SWI-Prolog, **backtrackable assert** can be implemented with the built-in predicate [`undo/1`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=undo/1):

```
b_assertz(Term) :-
    assertz(Term, Ref),
    undo(erase(Ref)).
```

Example **without** cut:

```
?- between(1,2,X), b_assertz(p(X)), between(3,4,Y), b_assertz(p(Y)), listing(p).
:- dynamic p/1.

p(1).
p(3).

X = 1,
Y = 3 ;
:- dynamic p/1.

p(1).
p(4).

X = 1,
Y = 4 ;
:- dynamic p/1.

p(2).
p(3).

X = 2,
Y = 3 ;
:- dynamic p/1.

p(2).
p(4).

X = 2,
Y = 4.

?- p(X).
false.
```

Example **with** cut:

```
?- between(1,2,X), b_assertz(p(X)), !, between(3,4,Y), b_assertz(p(Y)), listing(p).
:- dynamic p/1.

p(1).
p(3).

X = 1,
Y = 3 ;
:- dynamic p/1.

p(1).
p(4).

X = 1,
Y = 4.

?- p(X).
false.
```